# Muscles involved in Walking with different way

Tags: muscle, legs, walking

When I am walking  i observed I have two mode, in one I am walking normal way with all my body felling no tension, other one is in which my torso fill bit of stiff, it is feeling like walking by someone forcing me. Which muscles are getting worked out in both scenario?
I hope other people also experience same.